Find a base in which both of these forms are diagonal. Provide this form for both forms.
I need to find a base in which both of these forms are diagonal. Provide this form for both forms.
$f(x,y,z)=z^2+2xz+3x^2+y^2-2xy$
$g(x,y,z)=5x^2-2xy+y^2+4xz+2z^2$
I know how to bind a basis, where $f$ or $g$ is diagonalized, but not where both of them are. Don't know if it's useful, but that's what I got:
$f$ is $Diag(1,1,1)$ in $\mathcal{A}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,0,0), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(0,1,1),\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(2,3,-3))$
$g$ is $Diag(1,1,1)$ in $\mathcal{B}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,0,0), \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(0,2,1),\frac{1}{\sqrt{30}}(-3,-5,5))$

I don't think the question asks to diagonalize both $f$ and $g$ simultaneously.

"Find a base in which both of these forms are diagonal. Provide this form for both forms." thats what I have to do

Edit the question to include that exact text.

done :) hope it helps

are you sure you wrote down the forms correctly? $f=(x,y,z)A(x,y,z)^T$ and $g=(x,y,z)B(x,y,z)^T$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 & 1 \ -1 & 1 & 0 \ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & -1 & 4 \ -1 & 1 & 0 \ 4 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, but $AB\neq BA$, so these two matrices cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.

yup, it's correct

@zaba12 then i don't think such a basis can exist.

on matrix B you should have 2 instead of 4

why the equation AB=BA should be satisfied?

@zaba12 oh good catch, but they still seem to not commute. will write an answer.

Simultaneous diagonalization

To simultaneously diagonalize two quadratic form there are several (essentially equivalent) methods. I will proceed as follows. You define the matrices
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
 3 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\qquad B = \begin{pmatrix}
 5 & -1 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\, $$
with $f(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)^T A(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)^T B(x,y,z)\,.$
We solve the generalized eigenvalue problem
$$ A v = \lambda B v\,.$$
And obtain the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_1 &= 1, & v_1&= \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^T,\\
\lambda_2 &= \frac12, & v_2 &= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\end{pmatrix}^T,\\
\lambda_3 &= \frac12, & v_3 &= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -1&-1&2\end{pmatrix}^T\,;
\end{align} $$
here, the normalization was chosen such that $$v_j^T B v_l = \delta_{jl}.$$
Moreover, we have (from the eigenvalue condition) that
$$ v_j^T A v_l = \lambda_j \delta_{jl}\,.$$
Thus, the quadratic forms are diagonalized simultaneously in the basis $v_j$.
In terms of quadratic forms, we can introduce the new variables $x',y',z'$ with
$$ x= \frac12(y'-z'), \quad y= x'+\frac12 (y'-z'), \quad z =z'\,.$$
In terms of these variables, the quadratic forms are given by
$$f = x'^2 + \frac12 y'^2 + \frac12 z'^2, \qquad g= x'^2 + y'^2 +z'^2\,. $$

wait so this works even if $A$ and $B$ do not commute?

@AnCar: yes, you can diagonalize two quadratic forms $A,B$ simultaneously (there are some degenerate cases which you can avoid by assuming that one is positive definite); e.g., there is an invertible matrix $T$ such that $T^T A T $ and $T^T B T$ are diagonal.

I guess you mixing it up with similarity transforms: if you want $T^{-1} A T$ and $T^{-1} B T $ simultaneously diagonal, you need that $A$ and $B$ commute.

thanks, I learned something new. I guess this means that you can also diagonalize a psd matrix without a unitary matrix. This is what I was missing I think.
